# Error 500 on ttf and woff files

Tags: craft3

I'm having trouble to load an ttf and a woff file in Craft 3. I'm getting an error 500. The files exists and when trying to access it via the browser it shows: Twig Syntax Error – Twig_Error_Syntax Unexpected character "" for both of the files. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Instead of letting us guess what the issue might be it would be more useful to show us your code and your file structure.

Comment: Hey Robin, There is nothing fancy going on actually. Just have a css style which is loading ttf and woff files. The chrome debugger shows error 500 and when i'm opening the file in the browser twig shows an error Twig Syntax Error – Twig_Error_Syntax Unexpected character "". Can it be some htaccess or twig error settings error ?

Comment: Most likely you didn't include them properly thus we need the code

Comment: This is how i'm loading the icon font: @font-face{
    font-family:icomoon;
    src:url(54da533830dd0c1910ac66aa608c303a.eot);
    src:url(54da533830dd0c1910ac66aa608c303a.eot) format("embedded-opentype"),url(f1d29a50c6ddc22d39bd7e3f0e5ce345.ttf) format("truetype"),url(ee2c51fe7b99ae8ee7a1e64c6dcf77d7.woff) format("woff"),url(00f344a009ddb271ecd750817ffdeee1.svg) format("svg");
}

Comment: Do you have your files directly next to your index.php`? Because that's where your code searches them

Comment: no, the assets are in the templates folder. I'm also loading css and js files and those are correct.

Comment: That's why we need to see your folder structure. CSS and JS files should not be in your templates folder. Because only your web folder is accessable via normal URL you should put those files into your web folder in order to access them via public urls

Comment: Thx Robin, the hint that the assets can't be in the same folder as the templates fixed my issue. Thx for your help.

Comment: That's why you should always provide more information. We ask certain things for good reasons

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that the assets files were in the same folder as the twig template files. Moving the files to the `web` folder solved the issue.

Comment: Your issue was that your @font-face statement was wrong, it was instructing the browser to load the files from a location where they did not exist.

Comment: Nope, it was not a 404, its seems that Craft somehow wanted to render the file as a template.